# Is there any way to auto-send a "no" response to a script?

Tags: linux, bash

For example, I have this script:

```
read -p "$(echo 'choose yes/no: ')" repl
case $repl in
    [Yy]* ) echo "yes";;
    [Nn]* ) echo "no";;
esac
```

I can run `yes | bash script` and the script will automatically output `"yes"`

I want to know if I can send a negative response to it and automatically output `"no"`. Sorry if this has been asked before but I can't find anything related.

Comment: Btw.: Use `read -p 'choose yes/no: ' repl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yes` repeatedly outputs a string that you give it as a command line argument.  The default string (if invoked with no arguments) is `y`.

So it sounds like you want `yes n | bash script`

Comment: The finest hour in programming: "I'm tired of answering questions popping up after a long time - let's make a program that answers them. Let's call it `yes`" :-)